# How to return hash values as a string using to_s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, hash

This is my code:

```
def return_rider_values(pol_option, pro_endorsement, prop_coverage, *par)

  rider_values
  par.each do |p|
    rider_values << RiderValue.find_all_by_rider_id(p)
  end

  rider_hash = { }
  rider_values.each do |rv|
    if rv.attributes["name"].downcase == "yes"
      rider_hash.merge!({par[0].to_s => rv.attributes['id'].to_s})
    elsif rv.attributes["position"] == pol_option.to_i && rv.attributes["rider_id"] == par[1]
      rider_hash.merge!({par[1].to_s => rv.attributes["id"].to_s})
    elsif rv.attributes["position"] == prop_coverage.to_i && rv.attributes["rider_id"] == par[2]
      rider_hash.merge!({par[2].to_s => rv.attributes["id"].to_s})
    elsif rv.attributes["position"] == pro_endorsement.to_i && rv.attributes["rider_id"] == par[3]
      rider_hash.merge!({par[3].to_s => rv.attributes["id"].to_s})
    end
  end
  rider_hash
end
```

The output looks like this:

```
rider_hash  #=> '22' -> 58
                '23' -> 61
                '25' -> 66
                '26' -> 68
```

I was expecting, and need apparently since it's not working later down the line:

```
rider_hash  #=> '22' -> '58'
                '23' -> '61'
                '25' -> '66'
                '26' -> '68'
```

I don't know why the lookup function later in the program wants the ids to be strings instead of ints. I just know that it does, and I can't change it since lots of other methods use it.

I have `to_s` on both the hash key and value. I realize that in Ruby 1.9 `to_s` is an alias for `inspect` but even in the [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-inspect) documentation it says that, `inspect or to_s` is supposed to "Return the contents of this hash as a string."

So why is only the key being returned as a string?

Comment: I'm wondering, why you use `merge!` call instead of `rider_hash[par[0].to_s] = rv.attributes['id'].to_s`?

Comment: Could you make a runnable snippet that reproduces the problem? So far I don't see what could be the problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is there a difference? I tend to be more explicit simply because ruby isn't my first language (came from c++/java world)

Comment: Well, `merge!` does the same thing (in this case), but it's not idiomatic. Even Java people would use an indexer, I think.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev too me `rider_hash[par[0].to_s] = rv.attributes['id'].to_s` looks like `array[at index par[0].to_string] = some string` which seems like your using a string as an index, which is all sorts of bad!

Comment: Bad? PHP people would disagree. Anyway, it's not an array, it's a hash. Drop the bad java habits and embrace sweet ruby syntax! :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev a string as an index to an array doesn't work in c++, c, java or javascript. all the languages I used before ruby. :P And yes sir! dropping now... :)

Comment: Regarding your problem: I'm still waiting for runnable snippet :)

Comment: "doesn't work in c++, c, java or javascript" - ah, you didn't try C#. It supports creating indexer properties. Which Java doesn't have, I remember it now. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev working on that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I added a pastie, I think that should be runnable and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you actually *tried* to run it? It gives error to me.

Comment: It's not, but if there are string values in the hash, there are string values in the hash--I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. There are ways to see if a pastie is runnable on its own (e.g., running it on its own). It's a strange-looking method, though. What's `rider_values` supposed to be, an array? You should actually give it a value. What's the `else " "` supposed to do?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes `rider_values` is an array. debugging shows this: `rider_values = Array (10 element(s))` each of those elements is an `active_record` return from the database. Also the `else " "` wasn't needed anymore (was a holdover from different version of function)

Comment: @ryan the pastie worked with a few edits... view my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting what I wanted by adding this:

```
rider_hash.each{ |_,v| v.replace "'#{v}'"}
```

But this seems like a dirty solution somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of hashes so try this:

```
def return_rider_values
    par = [1,2,3,6]
    rider_hash = {}
    rider_values = [element1: {:attributes => {:id => 1, :name => 'yes', :position => 1, :rider_id => 1}}, 
                    element2: {:attributes => {:id => 2, :name => 'no', :position => 2, :rider_id => 2}},
                    element3: {:attributes => {:id => 3, :name => 'something', :position => 1, :rider_id => 3}}, 
                    element4: {:attributes => {:id => 4, :name => 'something_else', :position => 2,   :rider_id => 6}}]

    rider_values.each_with_index do |hash, idx|
        rider_values[idx].each_pair do |k, v|
            if v[:attributes][:name].downcase == "yes"
                rider_hash.merge!({par[0].to_s => v[:attributes][:id].to_s})

            elsif v[:attributes][:position] == 2 && v[:attributes][:rider_id] == par[1]
                rider_hash.merge!({par[1].to_s => v[:attributes][:id].to_s})

            elsif v[:attributes][:position] == 3 && v[:attributes][:rider_id] == par[2]
                rider_hash.merge!({par[2].to_s => v[:attributes][:id].to_s})

            elsif v[:attributes][:position] == 4 && v[:attributes][:rider_id] == par[3]
                rider_hash.merge!({par[3].to_s => v[:attributes][:id].to_s})

            end
        end
    end
rider_hash
end

test = return_rider_values

puts test
```

output: `#=> {"1"=>"1", "2"=>"2"}`